# php error - loop running one time extra?

Tags: php, mysql

I have written php script to read the content from text file and insert them into database. The text file have has just 3 entries but while loop is running 4 times. Don't know why??

Here, is the script

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die("Could not connect to server");
$db = mysql_select_db("bolly_songs",$con) or die("Could not select database");

$file1 = "ex_name.txt";
$file2 = "ex_link.txt";

$fp1 = fopen($file1,"r");
$fp2 = fopen($file2,"r");

$ctr =1 ;

while(!feof($fp1)){
    $text1 = fgets($fp1);
    $text2 = fgets($fp2);

    $id = "emov".$ctr;

    $query = "insert into example_table(movie_name, movie_link,movie_id) values('$text1', '$text2','$id')";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed ".mysql_error());

    echo "Data inserted in field $ctr with id as $id \n";
    $ctr++;
}

fclose($fp1);
fclose($fp2);
```

As the script is running one time extra, it inserts a row in table with just $id value and rest both fields empty.
Thanks!!

Comment: What happens when you initialize your counter to 0 instead of 1?

Comment: Sure you dont have a newline at the end of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets` returns false if there's nothing to read, so check for it returning (===) false within your loop, or change your loop to this example from the documentation:

```
while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```